# thecodemine branch form - change value of submit button on first step

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, branch

Does anyone know how to change the value of the Submit button on the very first step of thecodemine branch form? In the jquery it seems it was written to just have a "Next" and "Back" button, but nothing to identify the first step. I would ideally like the Submit button to read "Getting Started" on the first step, the next step(s) would read "Next" and then the last step read "Submit".

https://github.com/thecodemine/formwizard

```
(function($){
$.widget("ui.formwizard", {

    _init: function() {

        var wizard = this;
        var formOptionsSuccess = this.options.formOptions.success;
        var formOptionsComplete = this.options.formOptions.complete;
        var formOptionsBeforeSend = this.options.formOptions.beforeSend;
        var formOptionsBeforeSubmit = this.options.formOptions.beforeSubmit;
        var formOptionsBeforeSerialize = this.options.formOptions.beforeSerialize;
        this.options.formOptions = $.extend(this.options.formOptions,{
            success : function(responseText, textStatus, xhr){
                if(formOptionsSuccess){
                    formOptionsSuccess(responseText, textStatus, xhr);
                }
                if(wizard.options.formOptions && wizard.options.formOptions.resetForm || !wizard.options.formOptions){
                    wizard._reset();
                }
            },
            complete : function(xhr, textStatus){
                if(formOptionsComplete){
                    formOptionsComplete(xhr, textStatus);
                }
                wizard._enableNavigation();
            },
            beforeSubmit : function(arr, theForm, options) {
                if(formOptionsBeforeSubmit){
                    var shouldSubmit = formOptionsBeforeSubmit(arr, theForm, options);
                    if(!shouldSubmit)
                        wizard._enableNavigation();
                    return shouldSubmit;
                }
            },
            beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                if(formOptionsBeforeSend){
                    var shouldSubmit = formOptionsBeforeSend(xhr);
                    if(!shouldSubmit)
                        wizard._enableNavigation();
                    return shouldSubmit;
                }
            },
            beforeSerialize: function(form, options) {
                if(formOptionsBeforeSerialize){
                    var shouldSubmit = formOptionsBeforeSerialize(form, options);
                    if(!shouldSubmit)
                        wizard._enableNavigation();
                    return shouldSubmit;
                }
            }
        });

        if (this.options.historyEnabled) {
            $.bbq.removeState("_" + $(this.element).attr('id'));
        }

        this.steps = this.element.find(".step").hide();

        this.firstStep = this.steps.eq(0).attr("id");
        this.activatedSteps = new Array();
        this.isLastStep = false;
        this.previousStep = undefined;
        this.currentStep = this.steps.eq(0).attr("id");
        this.nextButton = this.element.find(this.options.next)
                .click(function() {
                    return wizard._next();
                });

        this.nextButtonInitinalValue = this.nextButton.val();
        this.nextButton.val(this.options.textNext);

            this.backButton = this.element.find(this.options.back)
                .click(function() {
                    wizard._back();return false;
                });

            this.backButtonInitinalValue = this.backButton.val();
            this.backButton.val(this.options.textBack);

        if(this.options.validationEnabled && jQuery().validate  == undefined){
            this.options.validationEnabled = false;
            if( (window['console'] !== undefined) ){
                console.log("%s", "validationEnabled option set, but the validation plugin is not included");
            }
        }else if(this.options.validationEnabled){
            this.element.validate(this.options.validationOptions);
        }
        if(this.options.formPluginEnabled && jQuery().ajaxSubmit == undefined){
            this.options.formPluginEnabled = false;
            if( (window['console'] !== undefined) ){
                console.log("%s", "formPluginEnabled option set but the form plugin is not included");
            }
        }

        if(this.options.disableInputFields == true){
            $(this.steps).find(":input:not('.wizard-ignore')").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }

        if(this.options.historyEnabled){
            $(window).bind('hashchange', undefined, function(event){
                var hashStep = event.getState( "_" + $(wizard.element).attr( 'id' )) || wizard.firstStep;
                if(hashStep !== wizard.currentStep){
                    if(wizard.options.validationEnabled && hashStep === wizard._navigate(wizard.currentStep)){
                        if(!wizard.element.valid()){
                            wizard._updateHistory(wizard.currentStep);
                            wizard.element.validate().focusInvalid();

                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(hashStep !== wizard.currentStep)
                        wizard._show(hashStep);
                }
            });
        }

        this.element.addClass("ui-formwizard");
        this.element.find(":input").addClass("ui-wizard-content");
        this.steps.addClass("ui-formwizard-content");
        this.backButton.addClass("ui-formwizard-button ui-wizard-content");
        this.nextButton.addClass("ui-formwizard-button ui-wizard-content");

        if(!this.options.disableUIStyles){
            this.element.addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-reset ui-corner-all");
            this.element.find(":input").addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-state-default");
            this.steps.addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-corner-all");
            this.backButton.addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-state-default");
            this.nextButton.addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-state-default");
        }
        this._show(undefined);
        return $(this);
    },

    _next : function(){
        if(this.options.validationEnabled){
            if(!this.element.valid()){
                this.element.validate().focusInvalid();
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(this.options.remoteAjax != undefined){
            var options = this.options.remoteAjax[this.currentStep];
            var wizard = this;
            if(options !== undefined){
                var success = options.success;
                var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
                var complete = options.complete;

                options = $.extend({},options,{
                    success: function(data, statusText){
                        if((success !== undefined && success(data, statusText)) || (success == undefined)){
                            wizard._continueToNextStep();
                        }
                    },
                    beforeSend : function(xhr){
                        wizard._disableNavigation();
                        if(beforeSend !== undefined)
                            beforeSend(xhr);
                        $(wizard.element).trigger('before_remote_ajax', {"currentStep" : wizard.currentStep});
                    },
                    complete : function(xhr, statusText){
                        if(complete !== undefined)
                            complete(xhr, statusText);
                        $(wizard.element).trigger('after_remote_ajax', {"currentStep" : wizard.currentStep});
                        wizard._enableNavigation();
                    }
                })
                this.element.ajaxSubmit(options);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return this._continueToNextStep();
    },

    _back : function(){
        if(this.activatedSteps.length > 0){
            if(this.options.historyEnabled){
                this._updateHistory(this.activatedSteps[this.activatedSteps.length - 2]);
            }else{
                this._show(this.activatedSteps[this.activatedSteps.length - 2], true);
            }
        }
        return false;
    },

    _continueToNextStep : function(){
        if(this.isLastStep){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.activatedSteps.length; i++){
                this.steps.filter("#" + this.activatedSteps[i]).find(":input").not(".wizard-ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
            if(!this.options.formPluginEnabled){
                return true;
            }else{
                this._disableNavigation();
                this.element.ajaxSubmit(this.options.formOptions);
                return false;
            }
        }

        var step = this._navigate(this.currentStep);
        if(step == this.currentStep){
            return false;
        }
        if(this.options.historyEnabled){
            this._updateHistory(step);
        }else{
            this._show(step, true);
        }
        return false;
    },

    _updateHistory : function(step){
        var state = {};
        state["_" + $(this.element).attr('id')] = step;
        $.bbq.pushState(state);
    },

    _disableNavigation : function(){
        this.nextButton.attr("disabled","disabled");
        this.backButton.attr("disabled","disabled");
        if(!this.options.disableUIStyles){
            this.nextButton.removeClass("ui-state-active").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
            this.backButton.removeClass("ui-state-active").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
        }
    },

    _enableNavigation : function(){
        if(this.isLastStep){
            this.nextButton.val(this.options.textSubmit);
        }
        else{
            this.nextButton.val(this.options.textNext);
        }

        if($.trim(this.currentStep) !== this.steps.eq(0).attr("id")){
            this.backButton.removeAttr("disabled");
            if(!this.options.disableUIStyles){
                this.backButton.removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass("ui-state-active");
            }
        }

        this.nextButton.removeAttr("disabled");
        if(!this.options.disableUIStyles){
            this.nextButton.removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass("ui-state-active");
        }
    },

    _animate : function(oldStep, newStep, stepShownCallback){
        this._disableNavigation();
        var old = this.steps.filter("#" + oldStep);
        var current = this.steps.filter("#" + newStep);
        old.find(":input").not(".wizard-ignore").attr("disabled","disabled");
        current.find(":input").not(".wizard-ignore").removeAttr("disabled");
        var wizard = this;
        old.animate(wizard.options.outAnimation, wizard.options.outDuration, wizard.options.easing, function(){
            current.animate(wizard.options.inAnimation, wizard.options.inDuration, wizard.options.easing, function(){
                if(wizard.options.focusFirstInput)
                    current.find(":input:first").focus();
                wizard._enableNavigation();

                stepShownCallback.apply(wizard);
            });
            return;
        });
    },

    _checkIflastStep : function(step){
        this.isLastStep = false;
        if($("#" + step).hasClass(this.options.submitStepClass) || this.steps.filter(":last").attr("id") == step){
            this.isLastStep = true;
        }
    },

    _getLink : function(step){
        var link = undefined;
        var links = this.steps.filter("#" + step).find(this.options.linkClass);

        if(links != undefined){
            if(links.filter(":radio,:checkbox").size() > 0){
                link = links.filter(this.options.linkClass + ":checked").val();
            }else{
                link = $(links).val();
            }
        }
        return link;
    },

    _navigate : function(step){
        var link = this._getLink(step);
        if(link != undefined){
            if((link != "" && link != null && link != undefined) && this.steps.filter("#" + link).attr("id") != undefined){
                return link;
            }
            return this.currentStep;
        }else if(link == undefined && !this.isLastStep){
            var step1 =  this.steps.filter("#" + step).next().attr("id");
            return step1;
        }
    },

    _show : function(step){
        var backwards = false;
        var triggerStepShown = step !== undefined;
        if(step == undefined || step == ""){
                this.activatedSteps.pop();
                step = this.firstStep;
                this.activatedSteps.push(step);
        }else{
            if($.inArray(step, this.activatedSteps) > -1){
                backwards = true;
                this.activatedSteps.pop();
            }else {
                this.activatedSteps.push(step);
            }
        }

        if(this.currentStep !== step || step === this.firstStep){
            this.previousStep = this.currentStep;
            this._checkIflastStep(step);
            this.currentStep = step;
            var stepShownCallback = function(){if(triggerStepShown){$(this.element).trigger('step_shown', $.extend({"isBackNavigation" : backwards},this._state()));}}
            if(triggerStepShown){
                $(this.element).trigger('before_step_shown', $.extend({"isBackNavigation" : backwards},this._state()));
            }
            this._animate(this.previousStep, step, stepShownCallback);
        };


    },

   _reset : function(){
        this.element.resetForm()
        $("label,:input,textarea",this).removeClass("error");
        for(var i = 0; i < this.activatedSteps.length; i++){
            this.steps.filter("#" + this.activatedSteps[i]).hide().find(":input").attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        this.activatedSteps = new Array();
        this.previousStep = undefined;
        this.isLastStep = false;
        if(this.options.historyEnabled){
            this._updateHistory(this.firstStep);
        }else{
            this._show(this.firstStep);
        }

    },

    _state : function(state){
        var currentState = { "settings" : this.options,
            "activatedSteps" : this.activatedSteps,
            "isLastStep" : this.isLastStep,
            "isFirstStep" : this.currentStep === this.firstStep,
            "previousStep" : this.previousStep,
            "currentStep" : this.currentStep,
            "backButton" : this.backButton,
            "nextButton" : this.nextButton,
            "steps" : this.steps,
            "firstStep" : this.firstStep
        }

        if(state !== undefined)
            return currentState[state];

        return currentState;
    },

  /*Methods*/

    show : function(step){
        if(this.options.historyEnabled){
            this._updateHistory(step);
        }else{
            this._show(step);
        }
    },

    state : function(state){
        return this._state(state);
    },

    reset : function(){
        this._reset();
    },

    next : function(){
        this._next();
    },

    back : function(){
        this._back();
    },

    destroy: function() {
        this.element.find("*").removeAttr("disabled").show();
        this.nextButton.unbind("click").val(this.nextButtonInitinalValue).removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass("ui-state-active");
        this.backButton.unbind("click").val(this.backButtonInitinalValue).removeClass("ui-state-disabled").addClass("ui-state-active");
        this.backButtonInitinalValue = undefined;
        this.nextButtonInitinalValue = undefined;
        this.activatedSteps = undefined;
        this.previousStep = undefined;
        this.currentStep = undefined;
        this.isLastStep = undefined;
        this.options = undefined;
        this.nextButton = undefined;
        this.backButton = undefined;
        this.formwizard = undefined;
        this.element = undefined;
        this.steps = undefined;
        this.firstStep = undefined;
    },

    update_steps : function(){
        this.steps = this.element.find(".step").addClass("ui-formwizard-content");
        this.firstStep = this.steps.eq(0).attr("id");
        this.steps.not("#" + this.currentStep).hide().find(":input").addClass("ui-wizard-content").attr("disabled","disabled");
        this._checkIflastStep(this.currentStep);
        this._enableNavigation();
        if(!this.options.disableUIStyles){
            this.steps.addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-corner-all");
            this.steps.find(":input").addClass("ui-helper-reset ui-state-default");
        }
    },

    options: {
        historyEnabled  : false,
        validationEnabled : false,
        validationOptions : undefined,
        formPluginEnabled : false,
        linkClass   : ".link",
        submitStepClass : "submit_step",
        back : ":reset",
        next : ":submit",
        textSubmit : 'Submit',
        textNext : 'Next Step',
        textBack : 'Back',
        remoteAjax : undefined,
        inAnimation : {opacity: 'show'},
        outAnimation: {opacity: 'hide'},
        inDuration : 400,
        outDuration: 400,
        easing: 'swing',
        focusFirstInput : false,
        disableInputFields : true,
        formOptions : { reset: true, success: function(data) { if( (window['console'] !== undefined) ){console.log("%s", "form submit successful");}},
        disableUIStyles : false
    }
 }
});
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to add:

```
if(this.isLastStep){
    this.nextButton.val(this.options.textSubmit);
}
else if { ////////// SECTION ADDED
    this.nextButton.val(this.options.textFirst);
}
else{
    this.nextButton.val(this.options.textNext);
}
```

I also tried to add

```
textFirst : 'Get Started',
```

But nothing is working... I'm not a JavaScript expert but I tried to see where "firstStep" was implemented in the code and try to change the value that way. It seems the plugin isn't recognizing the first step as the "first step" at all. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!! If anyone wishes to know how to have a different value for the button on the first step of thecodemine formwizard, here is how you do it:

add this under the _init function:

```
this.isFirstStep = true;
```

Add the code below the _enableNavigation function. This is to check to see what step you are on. My code looked like this:

```
_enableNavigation : function(){
        if(this.isLastStep){
            this.nextButton.val(this.options.textSubmit);
        } else if(this.currentStep !== this.firstStep){
            this.nextButton.val(this.options.textNext);
        } else if(this.isFirstStep){
            this.nextButton.val(this.options.textFirst);                
        }
```

And finally under the Methods Options section, add the code below and name it whatever you want the first button to be titled:

```
textFirst: 'Get Started',
```